# When does a system of linear congruences in multiple variables have a solution.

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic

If I'm given a list of m linear congruences in n variables, how can I efficniently (in polynomial time) tell if they have a unique solution, no solution or many solutions?

Example:

$a_{11}.x_{1}+a_{12}.x_{2}+...+a_{1n}x_{n} \equiv b_{1}\ mod\ 2$
$a_{21}.x_{1}+a_{22}.x_{2}+...+a_{2n}x_{n} \equiv b_{2}\ mod\ 2$
.
.
.
$a_{m1}.x_{1}+a_{m2}.x_{2}+...+a_{mn}x_{n} \equiv b_{m}\ mod\ 2$

Comment: Only $\bmod2$? Shurely shome mishtake, huh?

Comment: My use case is only mod 2. Feel free to assume mod k.

Comment: I'd imagine its the same complexity of row reducing a matrix. If your $k$ is prime then it should be the same as solving over any field

Comment: See [these slides](https://www.csc.kth.se/~johanh/sms07.pdf) for a nice overview of the answers to your question, and much more. In particular, the case $p=2$ is discussed, as you wanted.